# What's the unit of $request_length in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to know the size (I mean "bytes") of a packet sent to my Nginx reverse proxy.

So I add [$request_length](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) to the log of my nginx.

> $request_length
>
> request length (including request line, header, and request body)

But I'm not sure about the unit of `$request_length`.

Does it mean the number of characters of a request?

Or does it mean the number of bytes of a request?

Answer (score 3):

the unit is byte,
And, all of $bytes_sent、$body_bytes_sent、$content_length、$request_length、$upstream_response_length, the unit is same, is byte